# Get list of installed applications in Ubuntu via apt

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I installed a few applications a while back in Ubuntu using "sudo apt-get install". It's been a while since I logged onto my server and I am trying to perform some cleanup. How do I get a list of installed applications in Ubuntu if I installed them using apt-get ?

Comment: Please provide feedback if you down vote. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of installed applications using apt use the following command :

```
sudo apt --installed list
```